# Como fazer o titulo da página em cor azul?

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de saber se é possível alterar a cor da tag title.

Por exemplo, o titulo de SEO da página seria em cor azul **e podia terminar em negrito**

[image: Titulo da página em cor azul]

EXEMPLO:

```html
<title>O meu titulo da pagina em COR AZUL</title>
```

O meu titulo da pagina em **COR AZUL**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente, o título é mostrado na barra de título do navegador e NÃO na página em que os estilos são aplicados. Portanto, se você definir o estilo na tag title, ele não terá efeito algum.

Comment: Ok obrigado, como coloquei a titulo a mover pensei que podia mudar a cor.

Answer (score 1):

Isso não é possível. A tag [`<title>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-title-element.html#the-title-element) é um elemento de [metadado](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/content-models.html#metadata-content) do documento, portanto não é passível de estilização visual, como alterar cor, tamanho da fonte etc., nem mesmo aceita tags, o que torna inviável letras em negrito, ou seja, qualquer tag dentro da tag `<title></title>` não é renderizada e exibida como texto puro.

Comment: Ok obrigado, como coloquei a titulo a mover pensei que podia mudar a cor.